# HDMI mirroring on non-root EVO

Tags: htc-evo, hdmi

Is there any way to enable full HDMI mirroring on the HTC Evo 4g that doesn't require root?

I currently don't have the capability to root my phone as my charging port is broken so any suggestion along those lines is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

The newest versions of [FullHDMI](http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g-rooting-roms-hacks/63799-fullhdmi-official-fullhdmi-discussion.html) work without root, but my understanding is that the performance is degraded on unrooted devices (haven't compared myself, so I don't know if that's accurate or how bad it is).

Comment: Where can I get the newest version? The .apk file in the link provided installs but doesn't work. Can't find the dev website or the APP on Play.

Comment: @moesef: That is the newest version, and the app is no longer on the Market (it was briefly, but then was taken down). If that version doesn't work on your device then you're probably out of luck because I don't know of any other devs which even attempted an unrooted solution. Even the FullHDMI dev encouraged people to use custom kernels due to performance and reliability issues.